# How can I get the errorcode from the result of BeginConnect?

Tags: c#, tcp

In following code,

```
IAsyncResult result = tcpSocket.BeginConnect(IP, Port, null, null);
bool connectStatus = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(3000, true);
if (!connectStatus)
{
   throw new Exception();
}
```

sometimes the peer will return a [RST, ACK]; however connectStatus is still true. 
From result, I can see the errorcode is 10061.

Are there any function I can use to get this errorcode without using exception?

Comment: You are throwing the exception yourself. Aside from (a delegate) calling `EndConnect()`, what do you want exactly?

Comment: if remote computer is successfully connected, it will return [SYN,ACK], and result->[System.Net.Sockets.ConnectAsyncResult]->base->base->ErrorCode= 0; if remote computer is return [RST, ACK], ErrorCode is 10061. It can be viewed in watch (in VS2012). So how can I can get this errocode? Sorry for my language.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. If remote computer is return [RST,ACK], there is no exception, and connectStatus is true. I want to get a method to distinguish [RST,ACK] and [SYN,ACK].

Comment: I think you have to call EndConnect and catch the `SocketException`.

Comment: Yes, from EndConnect I get get the error code. Thanks Henk.